# how to show user name with associated posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-on-rails-6

I was building a rails app. I want to all post on a page. I am able to show posts title and body but i am not able users name(to whom post belongs -owner of post).

Post-Model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

User-Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts
end
```

Posts-Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end   
end
```

Posts-View index.html.erb

```
<h1> All article </h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <ul>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">
         <h5><b><%= post.title %></b> by <%=  %></h5>
         <p><%= post.body %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

Schema looks like

```
 create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Display name of user who posted that post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a relation to the `User` in the `Post` as `belongs_to :user`, So, you can simply use `post.user.name` to get the name of the `user` like.

```
<h1> All article </h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <ul>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">
         <h5><b><%= post.title %></b> by <%=  post.user.name %></h5>
         <p><%= post.body %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

## bonus

If you want to eager load the user in a single query you might wanna use. `Post.includes(:user).all`, its better if you always use the user, saves you  extra query. Mind that it has some downsides to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `post.user` to get `user` object. Then you can print any attribute from the `user` object.

```
<p><%= post.user.name %></p>
```

And use `includes` method to avoid N + 1 queries problem.

```
def index
  @posts = Post.includes(:user)
end
```

*Reference:* https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to access. Try `post.user.name` and you will get `name` of associated `user`.

Read here about all standard methods available for `belongs_to` association
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to